# Trying to compile running: 'node compile.js', but get error: “assert.js:399 throw err;” [Udemy 'Complete Developers Guide' Course]

Tags: solidity, solc

This is my hands on contract with this Udemy Course - Ethereum-and-solidity-the-complete-developers-guide

This is the contract file, which contains two contracts - Campaign and FactoryCampaign. I know there is a similar thread on this error that is answered in the link [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/82903/trying-to-compile-running-node-compile-js-but-get-error-assert-js350-thro)

However my problem here is slightly different. In my case, there are two contracts and I want to export these as two different outputs.

As per the course, this is the main contract;

```
    pragma solidity >=0.4.17;

contract CampaignFactory {
    address[] public deployedCampaigns;

    function createCampaign(uint minimum) public {

        address newCampaign = new Campaign(minimum, msg.sender);
        deployedCampaigns.push(newCampaign);
    }

    function getDeployedCampaigns() public view returns (address[]) {
        return deployedCampaigns;
    }

}


contract Campaign {

    struct Request {
        string description;
        uint value;
        address recipient;
        bool complete;
        uint approvalCount;
        mapping(address => bool) approvals;

    }

    Request[] public requests;

    address public manager;
    uint public minimumContribution;
    mapping (address => bool) public approvers;
    uint public approversCount;

    modifier restricted () {
        require(msg.sender == manager);
        _;
    }

    function Campaign(uint minimum, address creator) public {
        manager = creator;
        minimumContribution = minimum;
    }

    function contribute() public payable {
        require(msg.value > minimumContribution);

        approvers[msg.sender] = true;
        approversCount++;
    }

    function createRequest(string description, uint value, address recipient) public restricted {
        require(approvers[msg.sender]);
        Request memory newRequest = Request({
            description: description,
            value: value,
            recipient: recipient,
            complete: false,
            approvalCount: 0
        });

        requests.push(newRequest);
    }

    function approveRequest(uint index) public {

        Request storage request = requests[index];

        require(approvers[msg.sender]);
        require(!request.approvals[msg.sender]);

        request.approvals[msg.sender] = true;
        request.approvalCount++;

    }

    function finalizeRequest(uint index) public restricted {
        Request storage request = requests[index];

        require(request.approvalCount > (approversCount/2));
        require(!request.complete);

        request.recipient.transfer(request.value);

        request.complete = true;

    }
}
```

The compile code is;

```
    const path = require('path');
const solc = require('solc');
const fs = require('fs-extra');

const buildPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'build');
fs.removeSync(buildPath);

const campaignPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'contracts', 'Campaign.sol');
const source = fs.readFileSync(campaignPath, 'utf8');
const output = solc.compile(source, 1).contracts;

fs.ensureDirSync(buildPath);

for (let contract in output) {
  fs.outputJsonSync(
    path.resolve(buildPath, contract + '.json'),
    output[contract]
  );
}
```

Any help or direction to update the compile.js code to export the two contracts output successfully would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

That course is outdated you can ask for a refund. But I really recommend you not to do that, instead update your own code. Your problem is maybe because you may installed the new `solc` in your directory package which is not compatible with the old version of solidity, hence it is not working with your old JavaScript code.
I have the updated code for `pragma solidity ^0.6.6` you can use (this is the final code. it has some extra functions because in the end of that course the solidity code will be changed):

Here is the solidity Code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.6;

contract campaignFactory{
    address[] public deployedCampaigns;

    function createCampaign(uint min) public {
        Campaign newCampaign = new Campaign(min, msg.sender);
        deployedCampaigns.push(address(newCampaign));
    }

    function getDeployedCampaigns() public view returns (address[] memory){
        return deployedCampaigns;
    }
}

contract Campaign{
    struct Request{
        string description;
        uint value;
        address payable recipient;
        bool compelete;
        uint approvalCount;
        mapping(address => bool) hasVoted;
    }

    Request[] public requests;
    address public manager;
    uint public minContribution;
    mapping(address => bool) public approvers;
    uint public approversCount;

    modifier onlyManager(){
        require(msg.sender == manager);
        _;
    }

    constructor (uint min,address creator) public{
        manager = creator;
        minContribution = min;
    }

    function contribute() public payable{
        require(msg.value > minContribution);

        approvers[msg.sender] = true;
        approversCount++;
    }

    function createRequest(string memory description, uint value, address payable recipient) public onlyManager {
        Request memory newRequest = Request({
            description: description,
            value: value,
            recipient: recipient,
            compelete: false,
            approvalCount: 0
        });

        requests.push(newRequest);
    }

    function approveRequest(uint index) public {
        Request storage thisRequest = requests[index];

        require(approvers[msg.sender]);
        require(!thisRequest.hasVoted[msg.sender]);

        thisRequest.hasVoted[msg.sender] = true;
        thisRequest.approvalCount++;
    }

    function finalizeRequest(uint index) public onlyManager{
        Request storage thisRequest = requests[index];

        require(thisRequest.approvalCount > (approversCount / 2));
        require(!thisRequest.compelete);

        thisRequest.recipient.transfer(thisRequest.value);
        thisRequest.compelete = true;
    }

    function getSummary() public view returns(uint, uint, uint, uint, address){
        return(
            minContribution,
            address(this).balance,
            requests.length,
            approversCount,
            manager
            );
    }

    function getRequestsCount() public view returns (uint){
        return requests.length;
    }
}
```

Here is the updated Compile.js code:

```
const path = require('path');
const solc = require('solc');
const fs = require('fs-extra');

const buildPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'build');
fs.removeSync(buildPath);

const campaignPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'contracts', 'Campaign.sol');
const source = fs.readFileSync(campaignPath, 'utf8');
var input = {
    language: 'Solidity',
    sources: {
        'Campaign.sol' : {
            content: source
        }
    },
    settings: {
        outputSelection: {
            '*': {
                '*': [ '*' ]
            }
        }
    }
};

var output = JSON.parse(solc.compile(JSON.stringify(input)));

output = output.contracts['Campaign.sol'];

//will search for the folder to ensure it exists
//and if not, will make one

fs.ensureDirSync(buildPath);

for (let contract in output){
  fs.outputJsonSync(
    path.resolve(buildPath, contract.replace('.sol','') + '.json'), output[contract]
  );
}
```

Check the differences and learn.

Comment: Thank you very much Masoud, much appreciated.